# Additional length check to given RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I have the following RegEx:

```
valueRegex = re.compile('^(?P<DevID>.{2})(?P<CMD>TMPA|BATT)(?P<Value>-?[\d\.]+)-*$', re.I)
```

Now, I want to additionally check, if the given string has an exact length of 11 chars. Normally, that wouldn't be a problem, but in this case, I can't figure out how to implement it. Several attempts didn't work and I'm out of ideas. :/

Perhaps, I'm just blind to see the very easy solution :)

Here's the function where I need the string to be checked:

```
def parseMessages(llapMsg):
    rawMsgs = llapMsg.split('a')
    result = []

    data = [valueRegex.match(val) for val in rawMsgs]

    for val in data:
        if val is not None:
            result.append(val.groupdict())

    return result
```

Comment: `len(string_variable) == 11`?

Comment: ... can you not just do `len(string) == 11`?

Comment: I added some more code, so you could see, that this wouldn't work for me (perhaps I missed something...I'm new to Python, so if it so, please correct me)

Comment: Can you give us some input examples? What part should be 11 characters exactly? It'll probably be easier to filter the matches afterwards though, the expression will get ugly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be easier to just test for the length of the match *afterwards*.

With the optional `-?` part, plus both the `+` and `*` multipliers in your expression, altering it to match 11 characters is going to be.. tricky.

You could use the `MatchObject` `.start()` and `.end()` methods to quickly access the length of the match:

```
for val in data:
    if val is not None and (val.end() - val.start()) == 11:
        result.append(val.groupdict())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional checks that you need inside of the list comprehension. So, you can do something like this:

```
data = [valueRegex.match(val) != None and len(val) == 11 for val in rawMsgs]
```

Then, when you go through the list, the values will be `True` or `False`, so you want to simply check the value itself:

```
for val in data:
    if val:
        ...
```